# Ajax function returning "Request is not available in this context"

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, webforms

I am working on a VB.NET webform project and I am trying to use ajax to call a function that would then return an object to display in html.

Here is my ajax call:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    msgClickedClass.click(function (event) {
        msgID = event.target.id;
        //Get message body
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/secure/PortalMessages.aspx/PrintMessageContent",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "msgID": msgID }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // $("#dialogText").html(data.d.message);

                alert("success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert('Error: ' + status + '\nError Text: ' + error);
            }
        }) //end ajax


    }); //end click function
  });
```

Here is my vb function being called by ajax:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function PrintMessageContent(msgID As Integer) As Messages
    Dim msg As New Messages

    Dim db As New DB_SQL()

    msg = db.GetSpecificMessageSent(msgID)
    Return msg
End Function
```

When I debug the code, I do have a Messages object that should be returned, but the ajax function fails and returns a 500 error instead that says "Request is not available in this context".

When I change my PrintMessageContent to return a string instead of an object, the ajax function is successful.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** Here is what my Messages class looks like

```
    Public Class Messages
Private _TimeStamp As DateTime
Private _Subject As String
Private _Message As String
Private _Agent As String
Private _Id As Integer
Private _MessageViewHistory As List(Of MessagesViewed)

Public Property TimeStamp() As DateTime
    Get
        Return _TimeStamp
    End Get
    Set(value As DateTime)
        _TimeStamp = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Subject() As String
    Get
        Return _Subject
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Subject = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Message() As String
    Get
        Return _Message
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Message = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Agent() As String
    Get
        Return _Agent
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _Agent = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Id() As Integer
    Get
        Return _Id
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        _Id = value
    End Set
End Property



Public Property MessageViews() As List(Of MessagesViewed)
    Get
        Return _MessageViewHistory
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of MessagesViewed))
        _MessageViewHistory = value

    End Set
End Property

Public Property MessageHTMLFormat() As String
    Get
        Dim retn As String
        retn = Me.Message.Replace(vbCrLf, "<br />")
        Return retn

    End Get
    Set(value As String)

    End Set
End Property



End Class
```

Update #2: New Function:

```
 <WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
Public Shared Function PrintMessageContent(msgID As Integer) As String
    Dim msg As New Messages

    Dim db As New DB_SQL()

    msg = db.GetSpecificMessageSent(msgID)

    Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(msg)
    Return serializedResult
End Function
```

Comment: What is `Messages`? Also to get the value from webmethod, it return's a `json` object. You should get this by `data.d` property... Also try changing `data: JSON...` **to** `data: '{msgID: ' + JSON.stringify(msgID) + '}'`

Comment: @Zaggler , I have tried to access the value using `data.d` but the success function is never called. I've also changed `data: JSON...` as you suggested but I am still getting the same error message. I've also updated my question to include the Messages class.

Comment: Its possible that `db.GetSpecificMessageSent(msgID)` isn't returning anything or something is actually failing to return `Messages` object back... If you comment out all of the code inside the method and just put `Return msg.ToString()` and then change return type to `String` do you get the message id back?

Comment: `db.GetSpecificMessegeSent(msgID)` shows that it's returning something when I put a breakpoint on it.

Comment: Is it returning an instance of `Messages`? Show the code for `GetSpecificMessageSent` It should return a new instance of `Messages` and if not that's the problem. Also in your `Messages` class you don't have a new constructor.. Add this to the class: `Public Sub New () End Sub`

Comment: @SouXin is correct my bad. You need to serialize the object to return.

Answer (score 0):

Firs of all you defined returned data type as JSON, so you need specify return type:

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)> _
```

At the top of the file you need to specify Script service

```
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService
```

And finally you have to convert your object to JSON

```
 Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
 Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(db.GetSpecificMessageSent(msgID))
 Return serializedResult
```

**UPDATE**
I have noticed that you send object from ajax `JSON.stringify({ "msgID": msgID })` but never use deserialization. What is the purpose to do that? Anyway you just send the ID so you can change your code like this:

```
url: "/secure/PortalMessages.aspx/PrintMessageContent",
data: { "msgID": msgID },
dataType: 'json',
```

This should help as well.

Actually if you still prefer use stringify where is a small mistake in format. I had same kind of error in webservice. Try that:

```
data: "{'msgID':'" + JSON.stringify(msgID) + "'}",
```

This format help you to avoid error like: Cannot parse JSON primitive.

Comment: I changed my function to what you suggested but I'm still getting the same error message. Am I missing something? Updated function in question.

Comment: No you did not. Check my update, first. And second is it hit the break-point inside PrintMessageContent?

Comment: You have to remove content-type or use my second update.

Comment: I now get an error message that says "Exception has been thrown by the target of invocation" when it tries to run `Dim serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(msg)`

Comment: Can you add please try catch bloc and check exception ex.innerexception. Looks like you have somewhere NullReference exception

Comment: That's the error message I get inside of the try catch block and `msg` isn't null. The message I get in ex.innerexception is 'Request is not available in this context'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115123/discussion-between-souxin-and-bongo700).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was in my Messages class. For some reason, when I looked at a Messages object, it was returning much more than just the properties specified. It was giving things such as `Buffer, Content-Type, etc`.

I changed my Messages class to this and when I would hover over the Messages object, it would only give the properties specified.

Hopes this saves someone some time and struggle.

```
Public Class Messages

Public TimeStamp As DateTime
Public Subject As String
Public Message As String
Public Agent As String
Public Id As Integer
Public MessageViews As List(Of MessagesViewed)

End Class
```